# thorntail uberjar : reference an external module

Tags: wildfly-swarm, thorntail

i am quite struggeling on an implementation :

i am trying to make a generic uberjar, totally agnostic of the target environment.

In the meantime, i am referencing in my jboss-deployment.xml a module named configuration.

i would like that my uberjar generates a reference to this external module which is outside the jar, let's say /home/user/modules/configuration

I tried to use the additionalModules property of the thorntail plugin to reference this module, but nothing is working.

How do you do this guys ?

- having a generic uberjar
- having a module externalized to the uberjar which contains the environment needs

Regards,
Guillaume

Comment: OK
i diiged into this and figured out that with additionalModules,
 my module ended up into the modules path of the uberjar.

However, since its not added in the META-INF, the runtime still gives me WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: x.y.z

Any ideas how to make an entry into the uberjar classpath to tell the classloader to make my module?

Comment: At present I don't believe we support modules outside the uber jar.

Please raise an issue outlining the use case here: http://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN

Comment: Thank you Ken for your answer.
I will open a JIRA. However, id like to ask you : what do you recommend to have a one and single uberjar and add to the classpath the environment specific files ? (not only the project-profile.yml file)
add it manually as '-cp' in the boot command line ?
A thorntail module which was added to the classpath and referenced filesystem folders seem to be the most elegant way, from my point of view.

Regards,
Guillaume

Comment: I'm not sure why the environment needs aren't met with a yml file but requires a JAR?

Comment: @Ken for example providing keystore bins (not only jks paths in yml) per environment : those env specific bins are put in a folder registered as a bin for the uberjar. Same approach for total custom logback.xml per env and not just with some different values